# Removing sections of PHP programmatically

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to remove sections of code from a php file, programmatically.

I'm writing a program that has two versions, but I don't want to maintain two completely separate code-bases as they will be very similar. So I was hoping I could write one set of code, and remove sections that aren't needed programmatically afterwards.

I've tried searching around but can't find any examples of how to go about processing a PHP file after it's been created.

Essentially, I think I need to write another PHP program which opens my file, looks for a particular if statement and removes the if statement (and the code within it).

Eg:

```
if( is_version_b() === true ) {
    // do something different to version_a
}
```

In version_b of the system, this if statement would remain in the code.
In version_a of the system, this if statement wouldn't be in there at all.

I've looked into using `file_get_contents()` combined with `str_replace()`, but I feel like this is too simple for my use case, as I won't know what will be between the if statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you have when you just use an `if()` statement like that? Check which version you are in and act accordingly what you want to do.

Comment: The issue is that one version has premium features, which should be unavailable to the other version. My worry is that if the premium features are just hidden behind an if statement, they could easily be commented out.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but it looks like a regex is what you're looking for

Comment: @lukeseager You can use an `include` statement combined with an `if()` statement and don't deliver the include file for a specific version. Even if they change the `if()` statement they do not have the actual file to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're overcomplicating things.

From what you wrote it seems to me, that you actually need a version control system.
And the best one so far is [git](https://git-scm.com/)

When you will enable git for your project you'll be able to use branches and keep as many modified versions of your project as needed. Then when needed you can merge two brunches into one and keep only one set of changes.

Comment: I do use git, but mainly just as a storage space and for releasing versions with tags. So I'm a little unfamiliar with merging different branches of code to create combinations of code. I'll do some Googling though as I think this would be a clean way of separating out logic.